# How to capture zoomable image as one high resolution image?

Tags: extract

I would like to capture a zoomable image at a high resolution zoomed at 3x. Do you know of a way I can piece this image together without having to do it manually? [Here is the image](http://www.metmuseum.org/works_of_art/collection_database/european_paintings/rembrandt_1606_1669_as_a_young_man_style_of_rembrandt_dutch_about_1630_35/objectview_zoom.aspx?page=73&sort=0&sortdir=asc&keyword=&fp=1&dd1=11&dd2=0&vw=1&collID=11&OID=110001869&vT=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using bhups' solution, tweaking `outputx`and `outputy` for a good while, I tried something else.

I went back to the object page (in the above example, [here](http://www.metmuseum.org/works_of_art/collection_database/european_paintings/rembrandt_1606_1669_as_a_young_man_style_of_rembrandt_dutch_about_1630_35/objectview.aspx?page=73&sort=0&sortdir=asc&keyword=&fp=1&dd1=11&dd2=0&vw=1&collID=11&OID=110001869&vT=1&hi=0&ov=0)), took the thumbnail image URL (`http://www.metmuseum.org/Imageshare/ep/regular/DP145931.jpg`), replaced `regular` with `zoom` and to my surprise got what I presume is the full image, with less effort:

http://www.metmuseum.org/Imageshare/ep/zoom/DP145931.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You can tweak the URL to get the job DONE. [Here](http://media.metmuseum.org/mgen/metzoom/zoom3.ms?img=DP145931.jpg&wrapperid=11&outputx=1200&outputy=1601.067378252168&level=1&x=0&y=0&backcolor=0x00000) is the URl for 3x image. 
`http://media.metmuseum.org/mgen/metzoom/zoom3.ms?img=DP145931.jpg&wrapperid=11&outputx=1200&outputy=1601.067378252168&level=1&x=0&y=0&backcolor=0x00000`
outputx and outputy are the output image dimensions. level implies the zoom level. and x and y are the top left corner of the selected rectangle.